# Ramanujan resummation

Tags: divergent-series

according to the paper from delabaere

http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem01-02/delabaere2.pdf

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{k}= \zeta (-k)+ \frac{1}{k+1} $$

and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1}= \gamma $

but shouldn't all the results for a certain divergent series agree ? i mean there is an extra term $ \frac{1}{k+1} $ inside the divergent series although the function

$$ \phi (s)= \zeta (-s)+ \frac{1}{k+1} $$

is perfectly well defined and has no poles.

Comment: It would be better if the calligraphic [R]-symbol were at the sum in the first formula (like it is in the article on the last page) to indicate, that the sum is not meant in the standard way (in which case your first formula were false) but it is meant in Ramanujan's special way

Comment: -1 because still without correct modifyer in the first formula. The reference to the $zeta$-function looks as if in the Delabaere-paper were an error. In that paper is *not* the Euler/Riemann-zeta-function but an explicite made modification at that plcase and this is indicated there as such.

Answer (score 2):

Different summation methods for a divergent series may very well give different results. (Although the most common summations methods do agree on series where they are applicable; for example [Abel summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_summation#Abel_summation) and [Cesàro summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) give the same results when both are defined, but Abel summation is more general.)